# What is the correct way to style academic degrees after a name in British English?

Tags: british-english, abbreviations, writing-style

What is the correct way to style academic degrees in British English?

I've got a name:

> Jane Doe RN Dip HV BSc

My question is: How should I style the degrees?

> Jane Doe, RN Dip., HV, BSc.

or:

> Jane Doe RN Dip., HV, BSc.

or totally in another way?

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are no full stops used in post-nominals. The correct method for the OP name is:

> Jane Doe RNDip, HV, BSc

These articles may be of assistance:

[Post Nominal Letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-nominal_letters)

[List of post-nominal letters UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_post-nominal_letters_%28United_Kingdom%29)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It seems that the Dip. goes with HV, so am I correct to assume, that it should read as:

Jane Doe, BSc, RN, HV Dip. As I found at http://www.formsofaddress.info/Nurse.html

Answer (score 0):

If I read those academic degree correctly, here's the proper writing for them:

> Jane Doe, R.N.Dip., H.V., B.Sc.

Separate each capitalised letter with dots, but *do not* separate the abbreviation of one word (like `Science` in `Sc`). Separate each kind of academic degree with comma and space. And there's no space necessary between the dots.

Comment: I think “R.N. Dip.” is a single degree – don't separate it with a comma.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know what the degrees meant so I just wrote them the way I understood them. Thanks, I've edited it.

Comment: @Safira: Thanks for your response, could you point me to your source please?

Since I made the post, I have found following [source](http://www.formsofaddress.info/Nurse.html). He writes RN, BSc without full-stops, also he says that the order should be as follows:

- First Academic Degrees, 
then Professional Licenses (RN is a professional license), 
then Professional Certifications, 
then Professional Associations & Affiliations.

So according to his suggestion it should be Jane Doe, BSc., RN, HV Dip.

But it is an American source and I'm not sure, whether it'd be the same in UK English.

Comment: Well actually I know how to write it based on translated version (to my native language), but if you need a source, [here you go](http://www.accu-assist.com/grammar-tips-archive/GrammarTip_academic-degrees.htm). I think that person (in your source) wrote something about writing style in **envelope**, not publication like you meant in your original question (before it was edited).